# Is a particular meaning of "to decline" missing a noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns

When I [check with the net](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/decline) about *to decline*, I see a number of verbs with various meanings. At the same place, I can also see a number of nouns corresponding to them.

***to decline**: to grow smaller* has ***a decline**: a change toward something smaller or lower*

However, #9 and #10 seem not to have a noun *a decline* or "a declination* listed next to them. It seems so random and I want to verify it's not the case of a sloppy database or a PICNIC issue.

***to decline**: to show unwillingness towards*
***to decline**: to refuse to accept*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's right.

Language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it ought to be. There is no established nominalisation of *decline* in those senses.

Looking at *declination* in the iWeb corpus, in the first 100 examples, over 90 are the technical astronomical or related senses; five or six represent your last two meanings (and several of those are in legal contexts). And one is talking about grammar, and clearly means *declension*.

Comment: Interesting. What would be **stylistically** proper noun'ization of the following: *click here to decline the invitation* which then is followed by *confirmation of your ???*, then? I've considered *rejection* and *refusal* as well as *dismissal* but all of them sound so negatively charged and formal. For certain reasons we're required to use a noun instead of a verb and inging it won't do, so I can't *of your rejecting* nor *of your declining*.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I think I would use _your decline_ in that case. There a few instances of _your decline_ in that sense in the iWeb corpus, and several more where _decline_ has that sense and is used as a modifier and must be parsed as a noun and not a verb (eg _your decline letter_)